# Searching for similar like acts_as_ferret with more_like_this does with other search engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I've took a look at fulltext search engines for rails applications (acts_as_ferret, Solr, Thinking Sphinx etc.), especially their pros & cons. I found a very useful feature called `more_like_this` in acts_as_ferret, which finds similar records in database (great for similar products in eshops etc.). But I haven't seen anything like this by those others, does any of them have a similar easy-to-use feature like `more_like_this` in acts_as_ferret which offers the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Solr has a similar feature. See 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis and 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler.

Comment: And is there a way to access it via acts_as_solr from RoR application?